# local DNS server for dns caching OpenVPN clients

Tags: networking, server, dns, vpn, openvpn

i have two servers. One in the netherlands and one on australia.
They are connected to each other over vpn.
When a client connects to the australian server there is the netherlands dns server provided because its the primary dns.
Because of the delay I would like to create a local dns server on the australia server for the vpn clients that are connected to the australia server. But only for the vpn clients.
The server itself should get the dns from the primary dns server in the netherlands.

Currently the australia server is an oracle free tier server with systemd-resolved installed.

How is that possible ?

Comment: This is a very common setup for two DNS servers, and not really an Ubuntu question. It will surely be explained in the documentation for the existing DNS server. If it is an Ubuntu server, the DNS server is likely `bind9` and the [Bind9 Administrator Manual](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/) has all the information you need.